# "seen by" option in Community topics

Tags: community, topics

After posting a question on "topics" in community as a system Admin I can see "how many has viewed that post" and "who has viewed" but for a normal user they can only see how many has viewed the question posted (please see image). 
Is there a way to let some users to have ability to see "who has viewed the post"[image].

Answer (score 0):

Portal license users cannot see the list of users in the "Seen By" list.